# Change DisplayMetrics for application in Android (in API level lower that 17)

Tags: java, android, configuration, screen-resolution, dpi

I am working on the app, that has to look the same across devices. The problem is, if the device has a large resolution screen (for example `1920x1080` and a density of lets say `320`), then all elements start to look small.

On API level 17 and higher i can use this code to correct the problem:

```
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

    android.content.res.Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    config.densityDpi = <desired dpi goes here>;
    context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, displayMetrics);
```

But it throws an exception `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: android.content.res.Configuration.densityDpi` if the API level is lower.

So instead of changing the densityDpi in the config, i tried this:

```
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

    android.content.res.Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    displayMetrics.densityDpi = <desired dpi goes here>;
    context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, displayMetrics);
```

But this code has no effect at all :(. Maybe i am using it wrong? Can someone clear that up for me please.

UPDATE: So, no one knows anything about this? :/

Answer (score 5):

You just have to update both your config and displayMetrics like this.

```
 DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
displayMetrics.densityDpi = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW;
config.densityDpi = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW;

context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, displayMetrics);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at packages/apps/settings/display settings.Java Font_size  part, it uses Display metrics for scaled font property, but I think you need to use density property instead of densityDPI

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still looking for an answer. But try this:

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
displayMetrics.densityDpi = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW;
config.densityDpi = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW;
displayMetrics.setTo(displayMetrics);
config.setTo(config);
context().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, displayMetrics);
```